# c++ function call the destructor immediately after

Tags: c++, c++11

In the first main we will call the copy constructor for the initialisation of the two objects c and d. Then we will call the first = operator in my class then the destructor is called twice for the two objects and the output is I4I5c5d5d5

For the second main, we call the default constructor, then the copy for constructor for 5 and then we call the second operator in my class and at the end of the second operator the destructor is directly called.

I don't understand why in the first operator= the destructor is not called after the use of the operator and why in the second operator= the destructor is immediately called after the use of the second operator.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {

  int i;

 public:


   C() : i(0)                  { cout << "D" << i; }

   C(int _i) : i(_i)           { cout << "I" << i; }

   C(const C& _c) : i(_c.i)    { cout << "C" << i;  }

   C& operator= ( const C& _c) { i = _c.i; cout << "c" << i; return *this; }

   C(C&& _c) : i(_c.i)         { cout << "M" << i; _c.i = 0; }

   C& operator= (C&& _c)       { i = _c.i; cout << "m" << i; _c.i = 0;
                                return *this; }

   ~C()                        { cout << "d" << i;  }
};


int main() {

  C c = 4;
  C d = 5;
  c = d;
}

/* int main() {
  C c;
  c = 5;
  } */
```

Comment: You say `first main` and `second main`, what do you mean with those two? the first and second lines of code in main or two different versions of main?

Comment: If the output is `I4I5c5d5d5`, then the copy constructor was *not* called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `c = 5;` there isn't any assignment operator taking an `int` available, so a temporary `C(5)` will be created, and then used in the assignment.

This temporary will then be destroyed at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

First version

The last destructor calls have nothing to do with `c = d;`.

They are called because `c` and `d` are going out of scope and thus they're destroyed, so let's remove them from the result, which gives us:

```
I4I5c5
```

The first `I4` and `I5` are objects constructed by the statements `= 4` and `= 5` respectively, they are nameless temporaries created by the constructor that accepts an `int`.

But wait, if we are assigning `c` and `d` to temporaries why isn't our `C& operator= (C&& _c)` being called?

That's because of copy elision. The compiler is allowed to eliminate the moves here completely even if it would have side effects and it just constructs the objects in place. The code is equivalent to:

```
C a {4};
C b {5};
```

Then, the last one, `c5` is just because of `c = d;`.

---

Second version

For the second version this elision is not allowed because we don't construct the object immediately.. `C c = 5;` vs `C c; c = 5;`. So the move-assignment operator is called for the temporary created for the `5`, which is then destroyed immediately after the operator returns.